# How to state the exact probability that Y will fall between some number and another?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Given this:

In a simulation exercise, regression model ($Y_i = B_0 + B_iX_i + \varepsilon_i$) applies with $B_0 = 100$, $B_1 = 20$, and a $\sigma^2 = 25$.

¿How can you state the exact probability that $Y$ will fall between 195 and 205?.

I was given this question and I don't know how to solve it. Please, some guidance on it.

Comment: Are you familiar with probably density? Because the question you are asking is directly related to it.

Comment: The question isn't answerable because you provide only the variance of $Y_i.$  Do you want us to suppose the expectation of $\varepsilon_i$ is zero and that it has a Normal distribution?  If so, then for any stated value of $X_i$ you have all the information needed to compute any Normal probabilities, so please indicate where the obstacle might be to computing it.

Comment: I'm familiar with probability density.

Comment: I solved it with `pnorm()` in R. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `pnorm()` in R using this code:

`pnorm(195, 200, 5) - pnorm(205, 200, 5)`

Comment: It's not clear how does this answer your question? The solution seems not to be related to the question.

Comment: Where do the values of "200" come from in this answer?  You seem implicitly to suppose $X_i=0$ no matter what.  Perhaps this assumption is missing from the question?

Comment: sorry I didn't explain myself. I will elaborate my answer.